# Angular cli application deploy and I upload to server it's working fine but I reload it's not working in server

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have create a small site in NG-4 with Angular cli and it's working fine to my local machine with reload after I completed to this task I run this command:

`ng build --target=production` and deploy to this server `rohitazad.com/ng4-rohitazadmalik` and it's running fine but I reload to this than it's not working and I check to console then I show to one another message

> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

What can I try next? I'm new in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have an environment.ts file within your project.

You need to call "enableProdMode()" before you "bootstrap" your application.

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

You can search for "platformBrowserDynamic" to check if it is right configured.

After you check that all is fine you build your App by using

"ng build --prod"

or

"ng build --target=production **--environment=prod**"

Could you please show the whole console output?